# aarch64-elf-gcc error when compiling cpp file for raspberry pi 3 kernel

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, kernel

I am compiling a simple OS for Raspberry Pi 3 on my Linux Mint box using the aarch64-elf-gcc cross compiler.  I can do this with C but when I convert to CPP I get the below error.

aarch64-elf-gcc: error: ./src/kernel.cpp: C++ compiler not installed on this system

The compile line in my Makefile is
~/aarch64-elf-gcc/bin/aarch64-elf-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc 
-nostdlib -nostartfiles 
./src/kernel.cpp -o kernel.o

I know I have a C++ compiler because I use gcc for other CPP projects but being a ARM 64 Kernel Compile for Raspberry Pi 3, I do not know what I am missing.
Please help.

Comment: If you have C++ compiler for Raspi (e.g. `aarch64-elf-g++`), then use it. Otherwise I don't see how could we help you. The error message "C++ compiler not installed on this system" clearly says that your `aarch64-elf-gcc` is not suited for C++ code.

Comment: I do have the file aarch64-elf-g++ but I get the same error. is there a flag that I am missing in the compile line